# mapbox Navigation walking profite

Tags: java, android, navigation, mapbox

I have a issue corresponding to mapbox navigation profite route , I use options.directionsProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING) to have a walking route but the route is not a path for walking profile.
Here is my code

```
 NavigationViewOptions.Builder options = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
    options.origin(origin);
    options.destination(destination);
    options.awsPoolId(awsPoolId);
    options.shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute);
    options.directionsProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING);
NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(this, options.build());
```